# http traffic showing different directory than https traffic on apache

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-14.04, apache2, lets-encrypt

I have apache2 running on ubuntu 14.04 and had set up SSL using Let's Encrypt.

On one of my domains (domainA) it works fine. I can reach it at

```
http://domainA.com
http://www.domainA.com
```

or

```
https://domainA.com
https://www.domainA.com
```

However I have additional domains point at the box and have setup virtual servers for each of these. I set them up in the same way I setup domainA (see [this tutorial if you're wondering how](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04))

On my additional domains traffic over https displays the right dummy content - but traffic over http just shows me the root directory (so the default index.html shows up).

in /etc/apache2/sites-available I have the following:

```
000-default.conf
default-ssl.conf
domainA.com.conf
domainA.com-le-ssl.conf
domainB.com.conf
domainB.com-le-ssl.conf
```

They are all setup identically with only the pertinent information changed.

domainA .conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin me@domainA.com
    ServerName domainA.com
    ServerAlias www.domainA.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domainA/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

domainB.conf looks identical except with 'domainB' substituted instead of domainA. The domainA.com-le-ssl.conf file looks almost identical except for including all appropriate SSL files and being on port 443 (it's generated dynamically when I create the file with Let's Encrypt - I haven't touched them)

So domainB.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80
    ServerAdmin me@domainB.com
    ServerName domainB.com
    ServerAlias www.domainB.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domainB/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

DomainB.com-le-ssl.conf looks like this (identical to DomainA with only pertinent names changed):

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin me@domainB.com
    ServerName domainB.com
    ServerAlias www.domainB.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domainB/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainB.com/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainB.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/domainB.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

http and https on domainA work with no issue, both showing the same thing.

http on domainB takes me to /var/www/html

https on domainB takes me to /var/www/html/domainB/public_html (as intended)

DNS is pointing to my server fine for the appropriate domains - so I don't think it's a DNS issue as much as an issue with the configs or maybe the SSL?

Just wondering as to why and/or how I can change that? Does anyone have any ideas why it might have worked on the first one but for none of the others?

I feel like it's picking up 000-default.conf for HTTP traffic.

My 000-default.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you edit your post and add the configuration files for domainB (domainB.com.conf and domainB.com-le-ssl.conf)?

Comment: Done. Added the config files for DomainB per your request (although I figured out my issue listed in the answer below).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So apparently at some point the HTTP version of the sites had become disabled (potentially when enabling the HTTPS version).

Once I did the following they were working over both port 80 and port 443 (http and https respectively):

```
sudo a2ensite domainB.com.conf
```

Then I would reload apache with this:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Then it would pickup the configuration for the HTTP version of the site and direct it appropriately.

I decided I wanted all traffic to be forced to use HTTPS - so I added the following line to the HTTP conf (/etc/apache2/sites-available/domainB.com.conf)

```
Redirect permanent / https://domainB.com
```

Now if anyone tries to get to the site from HTTP it directs them to the appropriate spot.

Hope this helps someone else :)